# PHP Warning: file_put_contents(/home/username/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed to open stream: Permission denied in - on line 466

Tags: curl, composer-php

I need to install my sh file.

My sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs web/assets/logos
setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs web/assets/logos

npm install

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
rm composer.phar
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

When sh file step to:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

then shows error:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
    PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/ruslan/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed to open stream: Permission denied in - on line 466
    PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/ruslan/.composer/keys.tags.pub): failed to open stream: Permission denied in - on line 483
```

I don't know what happens with my Curl or composer. Help me please.

Comment: Next steps:  Downloading 1.1.3...

Composer successfully installed to: /var/www/html/project_name/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Installation request for jms/security-extra-bundle 1.5.x-dev -> satisfiable by jms/security-extra-bundle[1.5.x-dev].
    - jms/security-extra-bundle 1.5.x-dev requires php ~5.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Problem 2
    - jms/security-extra-bundle dev-master requires php ~5.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - jms/security-extra-bundle dev-master requires php ~5.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for jms/security-extra-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by jms/security-extra-bundle[dev-master].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting composer directory in your home folder and then reinstalling it:

```
rm $HOME/.composer -r
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```